# Access Redshift cluster deployed in a VPC

Tags: amazon-redshift, subnet, vpc, aws-security-group

I have my Redshift cluster deployed in a VPC inside private subnets . I need to allow an IP address to access the cluster from outside the VPC . To add that IP as a whitelist and access the cluster I tried the below .

1. Created an inbound rule in the security group which is attached to the redshift cluster . Added the ip-address/32 as source , port 5439 , protocol tcp , type redshift.
2. Added the redshift cluster in the public subnet .

I did check in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=134301 . He faced the same issue too .

The steps I tried didn't work . Appreciate any suggestion which can make that IP address to access the cluster.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- As the second step you did, I assume you've already put the Redshift cluster to public subnet in your VPC, then make sure your networkACL allows ingress port 5439 and egress ephemeral ports.

Comment: Thanks for the response . I was told to keep it in private subnet . I have to setup the NAT to make this work .

Comment: If you put in private subnet then you need and bastion host or openVPN server to make this work since NAT server or NAT gateway only serve outbound direction (and response) traffic, they won't allow inbound direction traffic.

Comment: Noted . I will work on this . Please edit your answer with the above details . I will update that as the answer . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your redshift cluster "publicly accessible". 
After that, just modify your associated VPC security group to allow access from specific IP addresses, and you should be able to connect to the cluster from outside the VP.

[AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=141686)

[AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-cluster-private-public/)

Comment: Hi.  When the cluster is in private subnet . Even if we make it publicly accessible will not help . I think we have setup up a NAT and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If the IP address which is outside the VPC of Redshift is in your AWS account, or in an other account; the VPC peering between two VPC can be an option.

If you peer two VPCs; one with Redshift and the other is the VPC of the other IP address, then it is possible two enable network traffic between two

You should enable traffic by routing tables entries for new IP ranges too.
And the security group entries should be added into Redshift's Inbound rules